# What do upvotes and downvotes mean on Meta?

Tags: discussion, faq, down-votes, voting, meta

What do upvotes and downvotes mean on Meta?
Does it mean "We should not discuss this," or "Good question, the answer is 'no'"?

Comment: Why would it mean the second?

Comment: Qiaochu Yuan.. well it seems bizarre to me but that is what it means according to the answers here.

Comment: Both of the answers below deal with proposals, not questions.

Comment: good question, I was wondering this myself. I will upvote this question because I think Meta needs more applesauce. I mean because I agree, I mean because this is a good question... oh hell.

Answer (score 18):

My interpretation of down-votes on questions:

- [bug](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug):
  **The bug should not be fixed.**
  This is not an important bug (is by design, cannot be reproduced, minor, etc.).
- [feature-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request):
  **The feature request should be denied.**
- [discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) requesting something
  (close/protect/lock/delete a post, merging tags, etc.):
  **The request should be denied.**
- [discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) about an issue where

1. the author presents their own views in the question:
   **This issue is not important/badly posed/otherwise bad**, *or*
   **I disagree with the view.**
2. the author does not present their own views in the question:
   **This issue is not important/badly posed/otherwise bad.**

Of course, ideally, people who downvote anything will leave a comment to explain why/suggest improvement, or upvote an existing such comment.

Answer (score 12):

The meta tradition is that a down-vote can simply mean "I do not agree with this proposal" or simply "I do not want this implemented." It's *not* necessarily a reflection on the *quality* of the question.

Part of meta's purpose is to field `feature-requests`. Higher-voted feature requests raise their awareness and are given more consideration. Hence, If you want to see a feature implemented, vote it up. If you *don't* want to see a feature implemented, vote it down.

As it follows, a similar justification applies to general discussions or anything else posed to meta.

Comment: IMHO, this applies only to feature-requests or proposals for implementation — which are what *you* are interested in :-) — and is not so applicable to general discussion.

Answer (score 8):

In meta.SO, an upvote means "I agree" and a downvote means "I disagree".

Comment: Downvoting this seems inherently amusing.

Answer (score 7):

What does it mean to agree with a question?  (Upvote this if you agree with me!)

Comment: I see that for this answer I have gotten my first meta downvote.  To the downvoter, I say: touché.

Answer (score 7):

I am adding this answer because the question came up again recently and, while much of what I wrote is a little redundant, there is an aspect of the *culture* of MSE which I think is worth discussing.

---

In general, a vote on the main site indicates that a post is poorly researched or of low quality.  On Meta, votes should, for the most part, be interpreted differently.  There appears to be a broad and informal understanding that a downvote Meta indicates that the voter disagrees with the sentiment expressed in a post, and that an upvote indicates agreement.

There is no "official" policy on the meaning of votes on Meta.  However, the help page titled ["What is "meta"? How does it work?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) has the following to say:

> #### Voting is different on Meta.
>
> Like normal Stack Exchange sites, Meta allows members to vote on questions and answers. For most posts, votes reflect the perceived usefulness: well-written, well-reasoned, well-researched posts tend to get more attention and more upvotes. Highly-voted and frequently-linked posts may become part of the community-curated FAQ or codified as part of the site’s Help pages.
>
> Unlike normal Stack Exchange sites, Meta invites the community to discuss, debate and propose changes to the way the community itself behaves, as well as how the software itself works. **On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement** with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.

There is also some commentary on the [SE Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/meaning-of-downvotes-in-meta-vs-main-sites):

> **On Meta**, however, many questions revolve around matters of taste (e.g. [the HW question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-users-answer-homework-questions)). When voting on answers to such questions, I want to be able to push down the suggestions that I disagree with and promote the ones that I think are correct. But I don't want to hurt people's reputation by doing so.
>
> Downvoting on Meta isn't really saying "your answer is stupid and wrong"; it's more like "I prefer we do it the other way". The whole site is basically meant to discuss matters of social preference, etiquette, do's and dont's, etc.

Finally, I think that it is worth repeating the following: the notion that "votes on meta are different" (including the idea that they indicate agreement or disagreement) is an aspect of the *culture* of Meta.  This is not an official policy, but is, instead, an emergent property of social interactions on Meta.

Comment: One must say that it's a bit confusing having upvote/downvote tooltip on meta saying "This answer is/is not useful" then...