# Trying to understand downvote criteria

Tags: discussion, down-votes, closed-questions

I recently asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4886413/integers-that-are-sums-of-two-squares/4886428?noredirect=1#comment10423808_4886428) after spending some time researching the web for an answer. It turned out that there was already a similar question on Stackexchange. I had not found it, but not for lack of effort. So my question was labeled duplicate and closed, with a link to the other question. I think that was fair and reasonable. But I do not understand why it was downvoted. The criteria for a downvote that I see when I hover over the arrow are "It does not show any research effort; it is unclear and not useful". None of these apply in this case. In the question I explicitly mentioned the research I had already done and time spent, and included a link. It was surely not unclear in its formulation. And I can argue it was useful because it attracted comments that clarified some of the topics. I am not posting this as a complaint, only as a genuine attempt to understand how to avoid downvotes.

Comment: With respect to voting on meta, you might want to read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/718/ (downvotes are different here).

Comment: Also, this *precise* topic came up [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65396863#65396863) earlier today.  "What is meant by "useful" can vary a lot from person to person. However, I am sympathetic to the point of view that if the answer to the question evokes the response "Oh, I was just being careless" or "Oh, I overthought it" or "Oh, that was really simple... d'oh", then the question probably isn't all that useful."  So a downvote might simply mean that the voter didn't find your question "useful", for whatever definition of "useful" they have in mind.

Comment: Downvotes can be freely made without disclosing the reason, and there are no penalties for wrongful downvotes. Downvotes cannot be completely avoided.